# What are some drawbacks/benefits of using ctools?

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

What is the purpose of ctools?

Are there any drawbacks in using ctools for one's programming needs?
Also, what are some benefits to using ctools? From the [project page](http://drupal.org/project/ctools) it seems to just be a large collection of random tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered the best place to learn this is actually from a [lecture from drupalcamp austin in 2010](http://2010.drupalcampaustin.org/sessions/ctool-plugins-and-exportables) by Erik Summerfield.

http://vimeo.com/17957123

That's just a start. Otherwise going through example ctools integrated modules has helped as well. The fact is (at this moment) documented use case examples are limited.